# Parse doesnt reflect the latest deploy sometimes?

Tags: parse-platform

I have noticed that, sometimes when I am working late night, There are issues with parse.com. 
Recently I was deploying my new file and it was reflecting them on the hosting link but I was still getting old code?

How did i made sure of the issue? I deleted some methods from my file to test it, uploaded it again and they were still working.

Has anyone else faced these issues?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered same issue but with storing data. The save functionality suddenly broke when accessing from Android device.

I have been searching for solution but it seems like there is no proper solution :(

Please let me know, if you find any.

Comment: I haven't faced this issue again.